# JBOSS-AS-MAVEN-PLUGIN :- Authentication Fails BUT Jboss-cli authentications?

Tags: maven, jboss, hudson, tomcat7, maven-3

I have setup a new JBoss server and am able to access it remotely using 'jboss-cli.bat'.

HOWEVER, when my Hudson job runs, and trys to deploy a war to the server using jboss-as-maven-plugin, it is denied access with the following error;

> ERROR: JBREM000200: Remote connection failed:
>   javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all
>   available authentication mechanisms failed

I am running;

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final
- Hudson 3.0.0
- Tomcat 7.0.35
- JBoss-AS-Maven-Plugin 7.4.Final

My POM contains;

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>7.4.Final</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>Dev_Deploy</id>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <force>true</force>
        <hostname>??.??.??.??</hostname>
        <port>9999</port>
        <name>admin</name>
        <password>password</password>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

My standalone.xml contains;

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="ManagementRealm">
        <any-ipv4-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="management">
        <any-ipv4-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-ipv4-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:902}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="443"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Could anyone put me on the right lines to solving this issue.
Many thanks,

Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to the [jboss-as:deploy](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html), it mentions as the following: -

> **name** String pecifies the name used for the deployment.
>
> **username**  String  - Specifies the ***username to use if prompted to authenticate by the server***. If no username is specified and the server requests authentication the user will be prompted to supply the username,
> User property is: `jboss-as.username`.

Then your plugin configuration should use `username` instead as the following example.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>7.4.Final</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>Dev_Deploy</id>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <force>true</force>
        <hostname>??.??.??.??</hostname>
        <port>9999</port>
        <username>admin</username> <!-- <----Change here -->
        <password>password</password>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: Hi Charlee,

It looks like this website has completely caused me issues in the head!!  Check out [this site](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-maven/maven-jboss-as-7-plugin-tutorial) , it appears to suggest that <name> is used to pass in the username for authentication.  How stupid am I to take MasterTheBoss as gospel.

Thank you so much,

Stuart